# Assign value to variable from ArrayList with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist

I need to extract the first 6 characters (ICAO) and assign it to a local variable from an `ArrayList` (taken from https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html) that looks like this:

```
["1234a5","ABC123","Schlumpfhausen",1572255699,1572255699,8.9886,48.3756,6278.88,false,155.16,216.64,-6.18,null,6484.62,"3026",false,0
"44035c","LDM87NM ","Austria",1572430045,1572430052,9.2009,48.6891,null,true,0,163,null,null,null,"6463",false,0
.
.
.
]
```

It is required to use `java.util.regex` to solve this Problem.

```
String icao=null;

    Pattern icaoPattern = Pattern.compile("([+-]*[a-zA-Z0-9.]*)");
    Matcher matcher = icaoPattern.matcher(sentence.getAircraftJson());

        if(matcher.find()) {
             icao=matcher.group(1);
        }
```

The outcome should be printed like this:

```
ICAO: 1234a5 | Callsign: ABC123 | ...
ICAO: 44035c | Callsign: LDM87NM| ...
```

but all I get is

```
ICAO: | Callsign: | ...
ICAO: | Callsign: | ...
```

Comment: Parsing structural languages isn't a great use-case for a Regex. There are libraries for JSON (or even for CSV - just remove the surrounding `[ brackets ]`) to ensure against many different classes of problem you could face.

Answer (score 0):

You want `group(0)` for the first match. The regex also needs some attention unless you can be very sure about the content always being clean. I removed the parentheses and changed the first `*` to `?` and the other to a `+` but there's a million things that could be done here to make it safer

```java
Pattern icaoPattern = Pattern.compile("[+-]?[a-zA-Z0-9.]+");
    Matcher matcher = icaoPattern.matcher(sentence);

    while(matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

Comment: group(0) comes out as the entire plane now - but i only want the ICAO: 
matcher.group(0):
`3d0d6d
DEDIJ
Germany
1572439422
1572439439
9.7958
49.0613
944.88
false
52.29
346.92
-0.33
null
906.78
7000
false
0
0`

Comment: In the context of `matcher.find()`, `group(0)` will return the match.  Try running the code I pasted (it works fine) then apply the changes back to your real code

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex to get every String including (or not) the double quote (") or any character except commas :

```
 Pattern icaoPattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|[^,])+");
 Matcher matcher = icaoPattern.matcher(result);

 while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group()); 
 }
```

In your code you run `matcher.find()` once (in if() statement). You should run it until it does not find any other match, thus the `while()` loop.

You can later use String methods to remove the leading and trailing quotes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern would match at the beginning or the sentence the empty string "".

Also the requirement of having the first 6 characters is tricky, only using regex.

The simplest would be:

```
Pattern icaoPattern = Pattern.compile("("
    + "[a-zA-Z0-9.]{6}"
    + "|[-+][a-zA-Z0-9.]{5}"
    + "|[-+]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9.]{4}"
    + "|[-+]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9.]{3}"
    + "|[-+]{4}[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2}"
    + "|[-+]{5}[a-zA-Z0-9.]"
    + "|[-+]{6}"
    + ")");
```